# jquery not working in laravel 5?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

In my `app.blade.php` main layout file i have included

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

{{-- CDN for JQuery --}}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

{{-- To include JQuery in any page with @section('jscript') --}}
@yield('jscript');
```

`@yield('jscript')` is used to insert jquery in different pages

So in my test page i have written jquery

```
@section('jscript')

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

It does not show the alert message on load.

I even included

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

directly in the file still it does not work

Comment: and what does your console say?

Comment: Do you see the `<script>` in the page's output when you view source?

Comment: Sorry found the problem. I had used the @section('jscript') twice on the same page